# EM waves with frequency much higher than gamma rays penetrate a planet like Earth?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, earth, gamma-rays

I have just started to study the electromagnetic waves as a personal interest. I wonder if there exist a much higher frequency of electromagnetic wave than Gamma Ray's which can even penetrate Earth. With our current measuring apparatus, is it possible to measure such high frequency waves if they penetrate everything?

Like passing through the earth without any significant energy loss?

Comment: First gamma ray is also EM waves ...there exists this kind energetic gamma ray brust.https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma-ray_burst?wprov=sfla1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For an electro-magnetic wave, the ability to penetrate matter goes as $1/{\sqrt{f}}$.

So as you increase the frequency, the penetration gets worse. By the time you get to gamma-rays, the energy is so high that the "rays" (at this point you're better thinking of them as particles - photons) interact with the matter and cause an electromagnetic shower of sub-atomic particles (read up on *pair-production* and *ionisation*).

If you want the wave to remain coherent after traversing a large body, you want a very low frequency. Radio waves in the few Hertz range have been used to communicate with submarine deep underwater. The data-rate is very low.

Comment: So there can be EM waves of very low frequency that can traverse a planet like earth?  Is it possible to detect them?

Comment: @user2979380 Radio waves can have any wavelength. If you are actually talking about _traversing_ the Earth, you have a problem because the Earth's core is made of iron - which is a conductor - and EM waves cannot propagate in a conductor. However, very long wavelength signals, on a scale of the size of the Earth, would pass our planet without being perturbed. The next problem is detecting - you need an antenna on the same scale.

Answer (score -1):

There are waves called *Cosmic Radiation* that have a much higher frequency than Gamma Rays do.  Some scientists also think that some Ultraviolet waves can have a higher frequency than Gamma Rays, but not bigger than Cosmic Radiation.

Comment: UV radiation, in the commonly used definition, does not have a higher frequency than gamma rays.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).